# libgdx & tiled how to render specific tiles?

Tags: java, 2d, libgdx

I have a large tmx map which I made in Tiled. I am using libgdx to render the tmx map. I would like to know how can I render specific tiles. For example I have a 100x100 tile/tmx map. Player entity spawns in 10,30 (x,y) I only want to render around the location of the player entity (or for any entity, and control the seeing distance within the respective entity class). How can I use libgdx to selectively render like this? I tried setting rendering bounds to camera but not working like I want.

I want to be able to zoom in/out of overall map (which would look dark/completely blacked out) except for the parts where an entity sprite is located. Looking to maintain the fog of war around the entity sprite.. and multiple entities.

Should I pass renderer into the entity constructor? multiple cameras? How can I do a layered effect where i have another 100x100 blacked out tilemap on top of the actual map and have it so the alpha around entities is 0? (bear in mind im using tmx maps)

Comment: AFAIK the default renderers only render the part which can be seen. How do you know that it's not like this? If you want something like fog of war, maybe a `ScissorStack` is what you want. Otherwise I think you'd have to implement a custom renderer.

Comment: You'll probably need a custom renderer, with which you register the entities and their view distance. In the render call, just render the tiles which are visible to those registered entities. I put this as a comment since I don't have a concrete example of this, perhaps if I find time to make an example I'll add it as an answer.